# \edef in LaTeX 3?

Tags: expl3, latex3, xparse

Is there a version of `\DeclareDocumentCommand` (in LaTeX 3) which performs like `\edef`? I.e. where the argument is evaluated at the time of definition as opposed to the time the macro is called?

For example

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_zero_new:N {\fpX}   
\fp_set:Nn {\fpX} {6}   
\DeclareDocumentCommand { \dX } {} {\fp_to_decimal:N{\fpX}}

\fp_set:Nn{\fpX} {12}

\dX
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

prints 12

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_zero_new:N {\fpX}   
\fp_set:Nn {\fpX} {6}   
\edef\dX{\fp_to_decimal:N{\fpX}}

\fp_set:Nn{\fpX} {12}

\dX
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

prints 6

and I would like \dX to expand to 6

Comment: Can you show a use case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The family of commands in `xparse` for creating new document commands are not really intended for this sort of thing. This can be seen in your example where `\DeclareDocumentCommand` is intermixed with `expl3` code.

The short answer is that the `expl3` version of `\edef` is either `\cs_set:Npx` or `\tl_set:Nx` depending if you're creating a macro that takes arguments or simply a token list.

In your example, instead of writing

```
\edef\dX{\fp_to_decimal:N{\fpX}}
```

you should just use

```
\tl_set:Nx \dX { \fp_to_decimal:N { \fpX } }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. Am I correct that the x in :Nx is what tells it to expand the argument? (as when I replaced it with :Nn it didn't work)

Comment: Exactly: `x` means ‘expand the argument fully (i.e., with `\edef`) before passing it to `\tl_set:Nn`’. See `expl3.pdf` or `source3.pdf` for a full explanation of the various argument types.

Comment: @WillRobertson, where do you get `source3.pdf`?

Comment: @daleif — It should be available with `texdoc source3` if you have a complete TeX Live or MiKTeX installation. Otherwise <http://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel>